# The transaction log for database 'master' is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have SharePoint 2013 on-premise server. Recently, It went down due to low space on disk drive. We have increased the disk space size

After the disk space expansion, when we tried to access the SQL server management studio 3 Databases went to recovery Pending mode

1. SharePoint_Admin
2. SharePoint_Config
3. WSS_Logging

Now, We are not able to perform any action on the databases not even on the master Database.

It's throwing an error "The transaction log for database 'master' is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'".
[image]

There are couple of answer given on the online sites like database shrinking, restore, etc. but we are not able to perform any action on the database.

Also tried to install CU14 for SQL Server 2014 RTM version https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/.

After the installation SQL services not getting started and in the event log same error was shown i.e. "The transaction log for database 'master' is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'"

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate: [Transaction log is full due to 'CHECKPOINT' for DB in simple recovery model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101585/140734)

Comment: @Larnu - I tried the above answers but here the case is different. I won't be able to perform any operation like changing the mode from simple to full, backup , shrink, alter, etc.

Comment: If you can't do that, I suggest that you get your DBA to fix the problem. This'll be unlikely something you can fix if you don't have any elevated permissions on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything when your transaction log is full, because any operation on the database must be logged to the transactio log...

There is many thing to do :

**First** try to drop some files on the disk that have the transaction log of master database. To identify the disk, use :

```
SELECT physical_name
FROM   sys.master_files 
WHERE  database_id = 1 AND type = 1
```

**Second** create another transaction log file on another disk. The Transact SQL command to do that is :

```
ALTER DATABASE master 
   ADD LOG FILE (NAME = 'A_NEW_TRANSACTION_LOG',
                 FILENAME = 'X:\.....ldf',    --> give a correct path and name
                 SIZE = 128 MB,
                 FILEGROWTH = 64 MB);
```

After you must analyze what it has been done, to prevent another similar problem.

Comment: I am getting error as  "Msg 5013, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The master and model databases cannot have files added to them. ALTER DATABASE was aborted." while trying to add new log file